# Modify Dash Plotly dropdown menu to manipulate multiple plots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Ok so I'm trying to make simple webapp with dash plotly. I have a couple of plots on my dashboard that I need to be modified by the same dropdown. One plot is a lineplot that shows how the data fluctuates in a 5 year period and the other is an animated barchart that shows the selected country's move for certain year.

The data is in shape:

| Country name | Score | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Finland | 12 | 2015 |
| Finland | 11 | 2016 |
| Denmark | 3 | 2015 |

And so on for 150 countries and a period from 2015-2020

Here is my code:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    [Input("url", "pathname")]
)
def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return [
            html.P("This is the content of the home page!"),
            #This is the code for the plots
            dcc.Graph(id='scattergraph', figure=fig),
            
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(id='linechart'),
                ],className='six columns'),

                html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(id='barchart'),
                ],className='six columns'),

            ],className='row'),
            
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_id', options=name_options,multi=True)],style={'width':'40%'})
        ]
    
    elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return html.P("This is the content of page 1. Yay!")
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return html.P("Oh cool, this is page 2!")
    # If the user tries to reach a different page, return a 404 message
    return dbc.Jumbotron(
        [
            html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognised..."),
        ]
    )
```

And below is the function to update the output, along with a screenshot of the result

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('piechart', 'figure'),
     Output('barchart', 'figure')],
    [Input('dropdown_id', 'value')]
)
#This updates the charts on the bottom of the home page
def update_data(chosen_country):
#     if len(chosen_country)==0:
#         df_filterd = dff[dff['Country name'].isin(['Netherlands','Iran','Spain','Italy'])]
#     else:
#         print(chosen_country)
#         df_filterd = dff[dff.index.isin(chosen_country)]
    dff=df.copy()
    df_filterd = dff[dff['Country name']== chosen_country]


    bar_chart=px.bar(data_frame=df_filterd, x="Country name", y="Score", color="Country name",animation_frame="year")
    list_chosen_countries=df_filterd['Country name'].tolist()
    df_line = dfcon[dfcon['Country name'].isin(list_chosen_countries)]

    line_chart = px.line(
            data_frame=df_line,
            x='year',
            y='Score',
            color='Country name',
            labels={'Country name':'Countries', 'year':'year'},
            )
    line_chart.update_layout(uirevision='foo')

    return (bar_chart,line_chart)
```

[image: bad output]

Answer (score 0):

Some questions I can't really see in your code:

1. Where is the DataFrame dfcon defined?
2. Where is the variable name_options defined? Have you assigned the labels and values for the drop down menu? You could do something like:

   ```
   dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_id', 
                options={'label': name, 'value': name} for name in name_options, 
                 multi=True)
   ```

Then the value of the dropdown will come into the callback! Be careful with your multi being True, if the user is allowed to pick more than one country then it could have issues when you are filtering the information, so you would need a new for loop.